# How do I get some state in or to a Apache Spark job?

Tags: apache-spark, scheduler

I would like to schedule a spark job regularly which should process new input files, if available and create some output files. How do I best manage the state which files have been already successfully and completely processed, so that a subsequent spark job run does not pick it up again?

Is this a responsibility of the caller (i.e. the scheduler?).
Should I move or rename the input files after processing?
What is the recommended way to solve such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there are following ways to solve the problem -

1. Using spark alone as what you have described - In this you have two options. One is scheduler or an event which would get triggered after some frequency and get all file names and process the files on the cluster. To maintain state, you can either decide some naming conventions such as .completed for processed files, .tmp for files in process (Apache Flume) uses this approach) or you can move processed files to all together new directory. 
   Other is one file watcher, which would poll directory for modification and pull the file once its modified or added. Then this file can be submitted to a spark cluster for processing. File watcher is preferred if you dont have any batch processing requirement.
2. Now, other approach is all together different. I am not fully aware of your requirement and purpose, but you can consider this approach if you want Spark to just process files and let some other technology like Flume to handle files or any such data as Flume is best in doing that. You can configure Flume agent with source as spooling directory in which you would keep files and sink as Spark (supports both the models - push and pull). By using this approach, you can leverage on Flume's capabilities of fault tolerance, file management and resiliency. Flume provides simple mechanisms for output file management and output format management.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for your answer!